# Constructor.newInstance vs Class.newInstance with a SecurityManager

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, when a SecurityManager exists that rejects access check suppression, Constructor's newInstance method works while Class's newInstance throws a SecurityException. Here's an example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission;
import java.security.Permission;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
                if (perm instanceof ReflectPermission && "suppressAccessChecks".equals(perm.getName())) {
                    throw new SecurityException();
                }
            }
        });

        String.class.getConstructor().newInstance(); // works
        String.class.newInstance(); // throws SecurityException
    }
}
```

Running this produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException
    at Test$1.checkPermission(Test.java:10)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:125)
    at java.lang.Class$1.run(Class.java:351)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:348)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

The JavaDoc for [Class.newInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) says that it calls checkMemberAccess and checkPackageAccess on the SecurityManager, but I don't know why it would call [setAccessible](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29). Is there a rationale for this difference in behavior?

I'm using:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.5) (ArchLinux-6.b20_1.9.5-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the code/comments?  This may show why it does what it does.

Comment: I just looked at OpenJDK's Class.java, and found this comment shortly before the setAccessible call: 

    "Disable accessibility checks on the constructor
    since we have to do the security check here anyway
    (the stack depth is wrong for the Constructor's
    security check to work)".

I'm still not sure why there should be a difference from the outside.

Comment: The comment explains it well, however to me it looks like a bug: This exception could be simply ignored, when setAccessible fails, then either it's already accessible and newInstance will work, or it isn't and newInstance will throw later. Both is correct, so ignoring the exception would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.newInstance()` invokes `SecutrityManager.checkMemberAccess(this, Member.PUBLIC)`, which - by default - grants access to all public members. `checkPermission()` is called (by `checkMemberAccess()`) only if the member in question is *not* public .

Thus, your overriding of `checkPermission()` will not affect access to public members. You need to override `checkMemberAccess()`.

Here are the relevant quotes from the Javadocs of [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> (`newInstance()` fails if) invocation of s.checkMemberAccess(this, Member.PUBLIC) denies creation of new instances of this class

And of [SecurityManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html):

> The default policy (of `checkMemberAccess()`) is to allow access to PUBLIC members, as well as access to classes that have the same class loader as the caller. In all other cases, this method calls *checkPermission()* ...

Comment: I'm afraid, you missed the point. The OP just does the equivalent of `new String()`, which is public and should actually always succeed, but fails for `Class.newInstance()` given his security settings.